# Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar Not showing darkactionbar on android 1.6, 2.3.3 and working fine on android 4.2?

Tags: android

I am using sherlock library in my apps. I want to show DarkActionBar >1.6 version but sherlock darkactionbar not working on version less than 3.0 but working fine on version 4.0 and 4.2. Here i am adding snapshot and manifest file of my project . I goggled lot but not got relevant solution. thanks in advance.

I have some question.
Q.1.How to solve compatibility issue in Theme?
Q.2. can anybody suggest me good tutorial for designing a compatiable UI?

following image on 2.3.3 emulator

[image]

following image on 4.2 emulator
[image]

manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.actionbartest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.actionbartest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your Activity Classes. It must extend SherlockFragmentActivity or SherlockActivity.